# How can I pass into an AngularJS directive some code that will be used by that directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this HTML which is standard in my code and used on many screen:

```
<button id="deleteButton"
  ng-disabled="home.rowSelected === null ||
               home.view == 'preview'"
  ng-click="ctrl.changeview(home.grid.view[home.rowselected], 'delete' )">Delete</button>
```

To simplify things I have converted this to a directive:

```
app.directive('adminDeleteButton', ['stateService', function (stateService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        template: "<button id='newButton'\
                           ng-disabled='home.rowSelected === null ||\
                                        home.view == \"preview\"'                        ng-click='ctrl.changeView(home.grid.view[home.rowselected],\"delete\")' >Delete</button>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // not used now but maybe later 
            scope.stateService = stateService;
        }
    };
}]);
```

However some of the uses of this directive require an additional check in the ng-disabled:

```
<button id="deleteButton"
  ng-disabled="home.rowSelected === null ||
               home.view == 'preview' ||
               home.grid.view[home.rowSelected].tests.length > 0"
  ng-click="ctrl.changeview(home.grid.view[home.rowselected], 'delete' )">Delete</button>


<button id="deleteButton"
      ng-disabled="home.rowSelected === null ||
                   home.view == 'preview' ||
                   home.grid.view[home.rowSelected].tests.length > 0 ||
                   home.grid.view[home.rowSelected].objectives.length > 0"
      ng-click="ctrl.changeview(home.grid.view[home.rowselected], 'delete' )">Delete</button>
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could make my directive a bit more flexible so I could pass into it additional checks that may be required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach functions (like `myFun` in the example below) to the scope of your directive like you would in a controller. Your first example rewritten:

```
app.directive('adminDeleteButton', ['stateService', function (stateService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E', //can only be element like <admin-delete-button home='home'><admin-delete-button/>
    scope: { //create own scope for directive so you can use the directive multiple times on the same page
      home: '='
    },
    template: "<button ng-disabled='myFun(home)'>",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.stateService = stateService;
        scope.myFun = function(home) {
            return home.rowSelected === null || home.view == "preview"
        };
    }
  };
}]);
```

For more details: [Angular directives guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Comment: what you are suggesting sounds very interesting and I think it would solve my problem but I am sorry. I do not understand how I could apply it to my example. Can you show me an example that would use my particular code. When I think of attaching a function I assume you mean a function in the controller but your example does not use a controller function.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand correctly, you want to be able to pass in custom additional conditions that will be checked to determine if the button should be disabled. you can do this with an additional scope variable (using something similar to mb21's solution above) that represents whatever other custom conditions you want. so something like:

```
app.directive('adminDeleteButton', ['stateService', function (stateService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E'
    scope: { 
      home: '=',
      additionalCondition: '='
    },
    template: "<button ng-disabled='myFun(home)'>",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.stateService = stateService;
        scope.myFun = function(home) {
           return home.rowSelected === null || home.view == "preview" || scope.additionalCondition
        };
    }
  };
}]);
```

and then use it like so...

```
<admin-delete-button additional-condition="myConditions"></admin-delete-button>

/* in your controller */
$scope.myConditions = /* some boolean value that will be used at the end of the chain of ng-disabled values */
```